# Phing not loading .properties file

Tags: php, ant, properties, phing

I have the following build.xml and build.properties files:

**build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="CoolProducts" basedir="../"
         default="dev" description="CoolProducts front-end">
  <!-- set default config -->
  <property file="build/config/build.properties" />
  <target name="dev">
    <echo message="{$dir.css}" />
    <echo message="{$dir.build}" />
    <echo message="{$dir.source}" />
  </target>
</project>
```

**build.properties**

```
dir.source = .
dir.css = css
dir.build = build
```

I expect my output to be:

```
css
build
.
```

but it is:

```
{$dir.css} 
{$dir.build}
{$dir.source}
```

Do I have something configured incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `${property}`, and not `{$property}` that must be used to display a property.

Comment: I realized I was doing this because I'm used to the smarty templating language's syntax: http://www.smarty.net/crash_course

Comment: @Andrew re:downvote - Haha don't feel bad :) +1 for the laugh.